# Is there any way to tell if you found all clues?

Tags: la-noire

When you are on a crime scene and look for clues, is there any way to know if you found everything and can move on?

I noticed that sometimes the location gets crossed out if you are finished there, but sometimes the location did not get crossed out even though I could not find anything more to do there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the options menu, you can specify whether or not you want feedback/help with the investigation sections.  The main one you'd be interested in is the background music, which will turn off the "investigation music" in a scene when you've found all the clues.

There is also a chime that plays for each clue, and it changes depending on whether you're near an examined clue versus a clue you haven't.  If you are playing on a console, there is an option to turn on or off controller vibration when you are near a clue.

Some people prefer to have these options on to assist them during investigations, but others prefer to have them off to increase the challenge and/or the realism.

Answer (score 8):

When you are investigating an area that contains clues, background music will play.  Once you have found all clues, the background music will stop.

Answer (score 7):

Really late answer, but I'm putting it here because I can't believe this was never pointed out before!

To tell if you have found everything and can move on, just open your notebook and go to the Intuition page. If the `Show All Clues` option is gray, it means you've found all clues!

[image: Show All Clues option grayed-out]

This is the surest way to know if you've found all clues before moving on, because [sometimes game-bugs can cause investigation music to continue playing even after all clues have been found](http://lanoire.wikia.com/wiki/The_Gas_Man#Known_Bugs).